# Dealing with infinities in predicate calculus

Tags: computer-science, predicate-logic

I'd like to develop a program capable of verifying basic expressions in predicate calculus. When working in finite domains, one can exhaustively check the validity of universal/existential quantifiers. The trouble is, infinite collections show up all the time in math. This means it is impossible to use the exhaustive approach mentioned earlier. To get over this hurdle I've thought of a few possible solutions: mathematical induction, and/or showing the predicate is derivable from a set of axioms/already proven statements. Ideally, I'd like to be able to create expressions like "let $x$ be an arbitrary integer" and then use what is known about the integers to prove stuff. How I'd go about doing this is still not clear. How are infinite domains tamed in predicate calculus?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is how are SMT solvers programmed. You should know even simple systems like Peano arithmetic are undecidable in general.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee I have a basic understanding of mathematical logic's limitations. It's still possible to verify somewhat interesting stuff though, right?

Comment: @MolossusSpondee also, would you be able to recommend any texts on SMT?

Comment: it's definitely possible to verify loads of interesting stuff. Unfortunately I don't really know much about SMT solvers otherwise I would have put an answer not a comment.

Comment: all good, maybe someone else will be able to recommend a text